# proof verification for $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=\infty$ where $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=A$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

We have the functions $f$ and $g$ for which 
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)&=\infty \\ \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)&=A\end{align}

I have to prove that $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=\infty$.

**What I've got:**

Let $N \in \mathbb{R^+}$. Then there exist $\delta_1>0, \delta_2>0$ s.t. 
\begin{align}|x-x_0|<\delta_1 &\implies f(x)>2N \\ |x-x_0|<\delta_2 &\implies A-N<g(x)<A+N.\end{align}

Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$. Then both of the above statements will be true. Which means that $f(x)+g(x)>2N+A-N=N+A$.

**My questions:**

- Is my proof so far correct?
- How do I conclude that this number $N+A$ is an arbitrary positive number? To me, it might be possible that $N+A < 0$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $N$ could, indeed, be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: you meant N+A arbitrary ?

Comment: Be careful. Do not use the same $N$ in both definition of limit for $f$ and $g$. This leads to confusion. Especially since you want the $N$ for $f$ to be as big as you want, and on the other hand the $n$ for $g$ to be as small as you want.

Comment: @nedgrekerzberg Yes, thank you! That's what I meant. And $N+A$ being negative if $A$  being so negative that the sum of them is negative. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and define $N=M-A$. You proved that there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-x_0|<\delta\implies f(x)+g(x)>N+A=M-A+A=M.$$And you're done!

Comment: Yes but if $M-A<0$ then $N<0$ and N is fixed to be a positive real number which is required for the definition of function converging to $+\infty$.

Comment: @Nikola Your proof works assuming only that $N$ is a real number. Since you proved what you proved for *any* $N\in\mathbb R$, you can use that fact.

Comment: I see now. So since $f(x)$ can be greater than any positive real number then it can also be greater than any negative real number and the proof works for any real number as you say. Thank you!

Comment: @Nikola I'm glad I could help.